# Is class a singleton or not . how to make a class as a singleton or a prototype - in Spring

Tags: java, spring, singleton

By default a class is singleton or not ..

```
public class You{
}
```

---

```
public class My(){
public static void main(String a[]){

You you=new You();

}
}
```

is `you` object is singleton ..
if it is singleton how to make it prototype ..
if it is prototype how to make a class as singleton..

Thank you in advance..

Comment: Read about singleton: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern

Comment: Learn Java basics before you jump in more advanced topics(Spring?)

Comment: while learning spring i asked this question, but forget to mention that this question is related to spring classes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> By default a class is singleton or not .

No that class is not a singleton, as it has a default 0-arg public constructor added by the compiler. So, you can create as many instances as you want for it.

> if it is prototype how to make a class as singleton..

I guess, the term `prototype` you are relating to the scope of `bean` instances in Spring framework. In Spring, by default all the beans are singleton. To make it prototype, you have to specify `scope = "prototype"`. But I suggest you to learn the basics of Java, before jumping into a framework.

There are various things you must consider for making a class singleton:

- Make the class `final`, so that it can't be extended.
- Make all fields `private final`
- Make the constructor `private`
- Use a `private static final` instance field in that class, and a `public static` getter which allows the same instance to be shared across application
- Save the singleton class from being instantiated while *serialization* and *deserialization*.

The best way to achieve all these is to use an `enum`, with a single constant in it:

```
enum You {
    INSTANCE;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

No, it's not a singleton. You can create multiple instances:

```
You you1 = new You();
You you2 = new You();
```

A singleton class *enforces* only a single instance being created, usually by including a *private* constructor, and a static method to retrieve the single instance. This can be achieved simply in Java using an enum with only one value.

Then:

> if it is singleton how to make it prototype

The term "prototype" has no meaning in Java. EDIT: If you're talking about Spring, [prototype is a *scope*](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/ch04s04.html#beans-factory-scopes-prototype) - and it's very Spring-specific.

Comment: +1 He has jumped into Spring framework without learning about the basics of Java and singleton. Spring framework has some term called prototype instance, which means non-singleton instance.

Comment: @JunedAhsan: Ah, yes. Looking at other questions, that's probably it. I thought he was getting confused between Java and Javascript. The complete lack of any mention of Spring didn't help :(

Comment: yes i jumped to spring with out proper knowledge in java .. but i am not worrying, i understood and i am looking back , i don't have any problem .. please don't comment on others problems, if possible give suggestions Thank you

Comment: @bhv: I would *strongly* suggest that you learn the basics of Java before diving into Spring. It will be a *much* more efficient way of making progress.

Answer (score 1):

> By default a class is singleton or not ..

No, you can create multiple instance to a default class.

> is `you` object is singleton ..

No.(See in the link attached ,why it is not).

> if it is singleton how to make it prototype ..

Again **No**, it's not a singleton. It's already a prototype (In your assumtion,non singleton)

> if it is prototype how to make a class as singleton..

[What is an efficient way to implement a singleton pattern in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70689/what-is-an-efficient-way-to-implement-a-singleton-pattern-in-java)

And finally:

Official docs on [Creating Object's in Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/objectcreation.html)